# Set python system path to project root directory: can not use absolute imports this way

Tags: python

If I have a project with the following structure:

```
.
├── another_sub_dir
└── sub_dir
    ├── random_module.py
    └── script.py
```

The project has two subdirectories. When I run my script.py from my root folder with the command `python sub_dir/script.py` and print the `sys.path` it prints the `sub_dir` as path. So `Users/me/project/sub_dir`. When I want to use the absolute import path in my `script.py` (`from sub_dir.random_module import random_func` it throws an error:

```
from sub_dir.random_module import random_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub_dir'
```

How do I set my project directory as the system path when executing the `script.py`?

Comment: If `sub_dir` is in your path, then you just need to import from the file in that directory. Just do `from random_module import random_func`.

Comment: Rest of the team uses the root as their path so that is not a solution :(

Comment: can you just add that to your path? `sys.path.append('Users/me/project')`

Comment: I do not want to keep adding and removing that every time. Feels like there must be a permanent solution.

Comment: Well `sub_dir` is not a package, why not make it one?

Comment: You need to add an `__init__.py` to your `sub_dir` directory, and then your import will work

Comment: Thanks :) I will try when I get home! Why to my sub_dir and not to my root dir btw? To make it a package?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you want to make `sub_dir` a package. You can do this by adding a file called `__init__.py` to it. You want your structure to look like

```
.
├── another_sub_dir
└── sub_dir
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── random_module.py
    └── script.py
```

You can then run `python sub_dir/script.py` from the root directory, and it will succesfully import from `sub_dir.random_module`.